# Find and convert an item in a scala list

Tags: scala

I am trying to find an item on a list while transforming the items such that the first successful transformation returns me the item I want. So say I have the following:

```
def trans(a: A): Option[B] = {...}

val list: List[A] = List(x, y, z)

val b: B = list.findAndConvert(a => crit(a))
```

So my findAndConvert above would return Some(b) for the first call to trans(a) that returns Some(b) or None otherwise. How would I achive something like this findAndConvert method?

Thanks
Des

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.view.map(trans _).find(_.isDefined)
```

views are evaluated lazily, so trans will only be mapped to the view until find returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `crit` is defined, and `trans` is not called in your example. So I assume you mean `trans` in both cases?

Scala collections are very powerful, just check the API docs if you find a suitable function. `find()` for example looks good.

```
def trans(a: String):Option[Int] = {
    val r = Integer.valueOf(a); 
    if (r > 3) Some(r)
    else None 
}

val listA = List("1", "3", "2")
val listB = List("1", "5", "2")

listA.find(!trans(_).isEmpty)  // => Option[java.lang.String] = None
listB.find(!trans(_).isEmpty)  // => Option[java.lang.String] = Some(5)
```